# Uncaught error substrate-node-template pallet-contract

Tags: substrate-node-template, pallet-contracts

I am trying to use latest substrate node template. I have added `pallet-contract`. The code compile but when accessing contracts from polkadotjs Developer menu, I got this issue.

```
Uncaught error. Something went wrong with the query and rendering of this component. Please supply all the details below when logging an issue, it may help in tracing the cause.

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'keys')

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'keys')
at https://polkadot.js.org/apps/page.5bd3c0a06b4aee4f.js:718:5728
at os (https://polkadot.js.org/apps/modu.8896a823ddffd6ef.js:2:106274)
at Bu (https://polkadot.js.org/apps/modu.8896a823ddffd6ef.js:2:126396)
at https://polkadot.js.org/apps/modu.8896a823ddffd6ef.js:2:123000
at _ (https://polkadot.js.org/apps/modu.5d78a093107b232f.js:2:63097)
at MessagePort.I (https://polkadot.js.org/apps/modu.5d78a093107b232f.js:2:63629)
```

[image]

This is my code [github repo](https://github.com/ganesh1233456/substrate-node-template)